# How would I read in the city name and coordinates from this text file?

Tags: c, file, io, distance

I'm trying to make a program that calculates the distance between two points on the earth as well as the azimuth. Then once I get the distance and azimuth I'll have to create a graph data structure that will use Dijkstra's Algorithm to find the shortest paths.

Here are a couple of lines from the text file. Each line represents the coordinates for the two city location that will find the distance between the two:

```
Cairo=  30:2:39 N 31:14:8 E |Cape Town=  33:55:29 S 18:25:26 E
Cape Town=  33:55:29 S 18:25:26 E |Cairo=  30:2:39 N 31:14:8 E
Cairo=  30:2:39 N 31:14:8 E |Lagos=  6:27:11 N 3:23:45 E
Lagos=  6:27:11 N 3:23:45 E |Cairo=  30:2:39 N 31:14:8 E
Lagos=  6:27:11 N 3:23:45 E |Cape Town=  33:55:29 S 18:25:26 E
Cape Town=  33:55:29 S 18:25:26 E |Lagos=  6:27:11 N 3:23:45 E
Lagos=  6:27:11 N 3:23:45 E |Birmingham=  52:20:10 N 1:53:25 E
Birmingham=  52:20:10 N 1:53:25 E |Lagos=  6:27:11 N 3:23:45 E
```

This is the format:

```
<lat> d:m:s <N|S>, 
where d = degrees, m = minutes, s = seconds (max(d) == 90)
<lon> is d:m:s <E|W> (max(d) == 180)
```

Is the minutes and seconds important?

This is my distance function using Cosine rule off this website http://www.krysstal.com/sphertrig.html:

```
void findDistance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) {
    float a,b,c;
    float distance;

    /*

    if (latDir == 'W' or lonDir == 'S') {
        //change to negative
    }

    */

    a = y2-y1;
    b = 90-x1;
    c = 90-x2;

    printf("\na = %f b = %f c = %f",a,b,c); 

    //convert to radians for trig functions
    a = a * DEG_TO_RAD;
    b = b * DEG_TO_RAD;
    c = c * DEG_TO_RAD;

    printf("\na = %f b = %f c = %f",a,b,c); 

    distance = cos(b)*cos(c)+sin(b)*sin(c)*cos(a);

    printf("\nCos(distance) in radians = %f",distance);

    distance = acos(distance); 

    float distDegree = distance*RAD_TO_DEG;

    printf("\nCos(distance) in degrees = %f",distDegree);

    distance = EARTH_CIRCUM * distDegree/360;

    printf("\ndistance = %f",distance);

    //return distance; 



}
```

Comment: Clarify your question. You need a way to read the city name and coordinates? The only question in your post is, "Are minutes and seconds important?" That is up to you to determine. How accurate does your program need to be? One degree at the equator equals approx. 40,000 km/360 ~ 111km, so if two of your cities may be nearer than that, the answer is "yes".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Birmingham is about 2º W, not 2º E.

Comment: Sorry fixed it. Okay yeah it probably does have to be that accurate. I would only have to modify that bit once before I call the function right?

Comment: Hmm guess there is a typo in the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty to sanitize your input and put each entry on one line, like so:

```
Birmingham=  52:20:10 N 1:53:25 E 
Cairo=  30:2:39 N 31:14:8 E 
Cape Town=  33:55:29 S 18:25:26 E
Lagos=  6:27:11 N 3:23:45 E
```

I also removed duplicates.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int  main() {
    char line[256];

    // data
    char name[64];
    // hour, minute, second, direction
    int lat_h, lat_m, lat_s; char lat_d;
    int long_h, long_m, long_s; char long_d;

    FILE *fin = fopen("in", "r");

    while (NULL != fgets(line, 256, fin)) {
        sscanf(line, "%[^=]=%*[ ]%d:%d:%d%*[ ]%c%*[ ]%d:%d:%d%*[ ]%c",
            name,
            &lat_h, &lat_m, &lat_s, &lat_d,
            &long_h, &long_m, &long_s, &long_d
        );

        printf("Name: %s\nlat: %d:%d:%d %c\nlong: %d:%d:%d %c\n\n",
            name, 
            lat_h, lat_m, lat_s, lat_d,
            long_h, long_m, long_s, long_d
        );

    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you have many entries on one line, split by separator and execute that `sscanf` on each piece.

Note: this answer assumes the title is your actual question. If your question is `Is the minutes and seconds important?` then read @Jongware's comment.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, but you really shouldn't take liberties with a user's input format.  It would be sensible and reasonable to define a structure to hold the data for a city, and to write a function to read one city from a string.  You could return the offset where the conversion stopped, or pre-split the line at the pipe symbol and call the function twice (which is probably neater). The function would deal with conversion to float and handling E/W and N/S. You might create another function to format an output string from the structure too, but that's going beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Also, on a more technical level, you can replace the `%*[ ]` conversion specifications with a simple ` ` (blank).  In fact, doing that means that `1:53:25W` with no space would be accepted and converted correctly.  You should also check that the `sscanf()` command returns the correct value (9).  If it doesn't, something was wrong with the format of the data.  One good thing about `fgets()` plus `sscanf()` is that you can print the data that was not understood; if you use plain `scanf()`, you've lost the data that was converted successfully.

Comment: I took the liberty to use one entry per line to emphasize the format, although you are right: some `%*[ ]` can be replaced with (blank). As I said in the post, for multiple entries on a line, split it by a separator.

Comment: The two-cities per line is part of the data format. (Edit) Although it then still has duplicates: A->B repeated as B->A.